# which secondary structure assignment algorithm is used by PDB?

Tags: pdb, secondary-structure

older releases of PDB used to specify DSSP as the 2ary structure assignment algorithm used in PDB, right now no algorithm is explicitly stated. Where can I find a reference for it in the database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the PDB assign the secondary structure tags, or just validate the one uploaded in the repository ??

Comment: DSSP 4.0 ?? https://github.com/PDB-REDO/dssp is used in PDB-redo

Comment: cant find any reference tough